# Local system doesn't forward to intended port defined in OpenShift proxy app

Tags: networking, terminal, python, proxy, port-forwarding

I've set up a proxy server via `OpenShift` based on [this tutorial](http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/running-a-proxy-server-in-us-via-openshift) and used a few days by forwarding my local system's ports to remote app's ports:

```
$ rhc port-forward AppName
```

The result in the proper way was:

```
Checking available ports ... done
Binding httpd -> 127.x.x.1:8080...
Binding python -> 127.x.x.1:15000...
Forwarding ports,
use ctrl + c to stop
```

But now, it only forwards to the 8080 port which doesn't meet the purpose (Redirects any URL to the default page of the app on OpenShift server):

```
Checking available ports ... done
Forwarding ports ...

To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address

Service Local               OpenShift
------- -------------- ---- ----------------
httpd   127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.9.145.1:8080

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

How could I recover this to the correct state? What did cause the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open ssh
type

```
ctl_all restart
```

and then

run again the script

Comment: Thanks. Actually `ctl-all` didn't work for me (`ctl_all: command not found`). But running the script again solved the problem. Also the app seems not to need restart until when it gets stopped. Do you now why the script stops time to time, whereas the app is up and running?